# Retrieving Error Information from eval function in javascript

Tags: javascript, error-handling, eval

I want to be able to get information about the error occurring when using eval.

For example, if the user inputs: s = 5, success will appear in box2.

If the use inputs: s = p, I want an error message like "p is not defined" or "error on line 1".

```js
document.getElementById('execute').onclick = function() {
  try {
    eval(document.getElementById('box').value);
    document.getElementById('box2').value = "success";
  } catch (error) {
    document.getElementById('box2').value = "I want to get information about what the error is, specifically the line number."
  }
}
const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
```

```html
<div>
  <textarea id="box" rows="10" placeholder="Enter Your Code Here:" cols="65"></textarea>
  <textarea id="box2" rows="10" cols="65" placeholder="Results Shown Here"></textarea>

  <br>
  <canvas id="canvas" height="500" width="500"> </canvas>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button style="width: 2cm;height: 1cm;" id="execute">Execute</button>
</div>
```

I tried using console.log but I kept getting the result of native function.

Answer (score 0):

You can print the error you `catch`. Other than that, I don't think getting line number is possible when using `eval`. You can try any of the properties of [Error object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) but most of them will be `undefined`.

```js
document.getElementById('execute').onclick = function() {

  try {
    eval(document.getElementById('box').value);
    document.getElementById('box2').value = "success";
  } catch (error) {
  
    document.getElementById('box2').value = error
    
    // optional:
    console.error(error)
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <textarea id="box" rows="4" placeholder="Enter Your Code Here:" cols="65"></textarea>
  <textarea id="box2" rows="4" cols="65" placeholder="Results Shown Here"></textarea>
  <br>
  <button style="width: 2cm;height: 1cm;" id="execute">Execute</button>

</div>
```